# x-up-calling-line-id header field is not available from new chrome browser update

Tags: google-chrome, http, spring-mvc, https, application-security

In my Spring MVC application, I'm using x-up-calling-line-id header field to get mobile number and the application was working fine with all web browsers .

But, with current updates of chrome browser, that header is not exist and application is getting issue. but, the application is working fine with Mozilla Firefox.

Please anyone help me fix this issue in chrome browser.?

**Scenario :** When client load the web page, get request is happened to this function and get mobile number from that. The application is loaded using **https** URL and get request is happened from the URL which is **http**.

```
    public String supportOnLoad(Model model,@RequestParam("sId") String sessionId, @RequestHeader Map<String, String> header, HttpSession httpSession) {

        try {
            //Get mobile number from HTTP header
            String mobileNo = header.get("x-up-calling-line-id");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            
        }
        return "mcc_view";
    }
```